# Acessar cookie salvo no navegador

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extensão

Pessoal como eu faço para acessar um cookie salvo no navegador?

Poder ser pela api do [mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAllCookieStores) ou pela api do [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

1. Você não pode ver cookies de outros sites.
2. Você não pode ver cookies http-only.
3. Todos os cookies que você pode ver estão na propriedade `document.cookie`, que contém uma lista separada por ponto e vírgula de itens no padrão chave=valor.

Para uma implementação que abrange o 3º caso você pode fazer a seguinte função:

```
var getCookies = function(){
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookies = {};
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    cookies[(pair[0]+'').trim()] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookies;
}
```

E usá-la da seguinte forma:

```
var myCookies = getCookies();
alert(myCookies.secret); // "do not tell you"
```

Fonte: [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252665/i-need-to-get-all-the-cookies-from-the-browser)

Comment: Por que o voto negativo? Qualquer feedback é bem vindo.